# Can't create unmanaged dll using C# and Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports tool

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged

I try to create unmanaged dll in C# (VS2010) using Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports. This is my code for test:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace UnmanagedDllTest
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static int Add1(int n)
        {
            return n + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I build this, I get an error:

```
UnmanagedDllTest -> D:\Dev\UnmanagedDllTest\UnmanagedDllTest\bin\x86\Debug\UnmanagedDllTest.dll
D:\Dev\UnmanagedDllTest\packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.6\tools\RGiesecke.DllExport.targets(42,5): error : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD5A0\UnmanagedDllTest.il(60) : error : syntax error at token '{' in:   {
D:\Dev\UnmanagedDllTest\packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.6\tools\RGiesecke.DllExport.targets(42,5): error :
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to contact the author of this tool for support.

Comment: you can also use another tool developed by `Rainmeter` which allows assemblies to export functions. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498651/is-this-possible-to-write-win32-dll-files-by-c-net/11983742#11983742

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent whole day trying to solve this issue and finnaly I found the solution!
I also have russian windows and after updating VS2012 to VS2013 my projects started to show the same error:

> error : syntax error at token '{' in:   {

I tried to change environment variables, but this did not help.
The only thing that helped me was changing default language of non-unicode programs. You can find this setting in "Control Panel > Language and Regional Settings > Additional > Change language for applications that dont support Unicode". I changed language to english, rebooted ... and profit!

Comment: You saved my night. Works fine for VS2015 too.

Comment: You saved my day. Works fine for VS2015 update 3 community under Chinese win 10

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in Russian version of Windows. User z3d1k from Russia and I am too. In .li file enter comments in Russian.

Comment: I tried the English version of windows, everything works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

**This bug has been fixed in the forked release.**
[DllExport/changelog.txt at 1f6b2d90599d17614782784c6b5bb37f05a2dea9 · 3F/DllExport](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/blob/1f6b2d90599d17614782784c6b5bb37f05a2dea9/changelog.txt#L47)

You can fix it by re-installing with the following command.

```
UnInstall-Package UnmanagedExports 
Install-Package DllExport
```